# How to use multiple tools in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline, terraform, pipeline

I need to use nodejs as well as terraform tools on build stages.The declarative pipeline I used is:

```
pipeline{
agent any
tools { nodejs "node12.14.1" terraform "terraform-v0.12.19"}
...
```

Only nodejs tool can be used. terraform is not installed and gives command not found error.

Answer (score 4):

We need to specify each tools on new line instead.

```
pipeline {
agent any
tools {
    nodejs "node12.14.1"
    terraform "terraform-v0.12.19" 
    }
...
```